# React HOC: how to access props passed by the parent compoent?

Tags: reactjs

I have this Popover HOC component. How can I access `closePopover` method in the children? as you can see I have passed it as prop but I have no way to access it in children.

```
import { useState, useCallback, cloneElement } from 'react'
import { EuiButtonEmpty, EuiPopover } from '@elastic/eui'

const CustomPopover = ({ children }) => {
  const [isPopoverOpen, setIsPopoverOpen] = useState(false)

  const closePopover = useCallback(() => setIsPopoverOpen(false), [])
  const onButtonClick = () => setIsPopoverOpen(isPopoverOpen => !isPopoverOpen)

  const button = (
    <EuiButtonEmpty
      iconType='boxesHorizontal'
      iconSide='right'
      onClick={onButtonClick}
    ></EuiButtonEmpty>
  )

  return (
    <div>
      <EuiPopover
        button={button}
        isOpen={isPopoverOpen}
        closePopover={closePopover}
      >
        {cloneElement(children, { closePopover })}
      </EuiPopover>
    </div>
  )
}

export default CustomPopover
```

I am using it this way:

```
<CustomPopover>
              <div className='flex flex-col space-y-5'>
                <button
                  onClick={() => setSortAsc(true)}
                  className='hover:bg-slate-100'
                >
                  Sort by Oldest Message
                </button>
                <button
                  onClick={() => setSortAsc(false)}
                  className='hover:bg-slate-100'
                >
                  Sort by Latest Message
                </button>
              </div>
            </CustomPopover>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a function as the child might be an approach here, i.e. for popover having

```
return (
  <div>
    <EuiPopover
      button={button}
      isOpen={isPopoverOpen}
      closePopover={closePopover}
    >
      // Pass in an object containing things you want to use when rendering,
      // in this case close function
      {children({ closePopover })}
    </EuiPopover>
  </div>
)
```

Then when using it, have a function as the child:

```
<CustomPopover>
  {props => (
    // So here you can access the object you passed into children({...})
    <button onClick={props.closePopover}></button>
  )}
</CustomPopover>
```

Comment: So, now any child of `EuiPopover` across the app can have access to `closePopover`function from props and trigger it, and assuming `EuiPopover` has childA which has childB and so on so, can the deepest child also have access to that `closePopover func` and because as this function is updating the state will all Components having access to this prop `closePopoverfunc` will re-render?